# In Scaled Scrum release management, how do you handle unfinished features?

Tags: agile, scrum

In scaled Scrum release management, what's the code management strategy if there are unfinished features in the code base?

For example, SAFe agile framework recommends all teams complete sprints the same day (they run on the same cadence).

Say all the teams are preparing for a release --- they all meet their sprint goals in the last sprint of the release, except for 1 team (a few stories are still not ready, must be done in the next release).

How does your team manage this situation in terms of your code branching or management strategy?

Comment: Why are the unfinished features in the same branch that you use to release from?

Comment: Is releasing after they're finished an option?

Comment: Also, what particular scaled Scrum framework are you using? Nexus? LeSS? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

A completely unfinished feature should still be in its own feature branch and hence not a problem.

A 'dev complete' feature which has been merged, then had other features merged on top, then had bugs discovered is the problematic one.

You can sometimes branch from before the problem feature and then remerge the subsequent ones, but really the only solution is to do a hotfix or roll back to before the problem feature